# How do i get 120v @60Hz 400VA?

Tags: electrical

So I'm in Australia and unfortunately we run on 240v @2A 50Hz.

I've recently purchased a neon sign transformer but just realised that its got the below [image: eg]

Doh! Wrong input. I'm wondering if there's any way I can easily get the required input from my mains (I've also got access to 3 phase etc)? Does the Hz matter? If it makes any difference, i'll be passing the output through a Rectifier later to (hopefully) get 6kV DC @ 30mA.

The other question is what is 400 VA referring to and how do I get it?

Comment: 1) I doubt Aussie households are limited to 2A!  2) 240 V is manly, be proud.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I've got a 15 and 20 Amp 240v line here, plus 3-phase :) And I think its fairly easy to get high current 470V as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is an old fashioned wire wound transformer, the 60 to 50 Hz will not matter, going the other way makes some difference though. If it's some sort of electronic switching transformer, it could be a problem, I've no idea.

The voltage difference is obviously a problem. The 400 VA is volt-amps, or watts. You don't need to get it, it just happens as a result of applied voltage and resistance in the windings. 400 watts isn't a huge amount of power, you may be able to find a step down transformer intended for travelers from North America. You may find such transformers cost more than the device you have. You may be better off getting a proper transformer and writing off the amount spent as a lesson learned if you are unable to return it.